# SQL Server error - The SET SHOWPLAN statements must be the only statements in the batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to generate a showplan table in SQL Server. I am getting this error when I try to do this

> Msg 1067, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
> The SET SHOWPLAN statements must be the only statements in the batch.

I tried on a simple query and the error still appear

```
Use Warehouse
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON;
GO

SELECT * FROM [Warehouse].[dbo].[Client]
GO

SET SHOWPLAN OFF;
GO
```

What exactly does the error mean by `only statements in the batch`? Removing the `GO` did not resolve the issue too (I thought GO created "batches"). Could this be due to SQL server rights?

Comment: `Use Warehouse
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON;
GO` is 2 statements... `Use Warehouse` and `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSMS (and a few other client tools), `GO` is used as a batch separator (though it is commonly mistaken for a T-SQL keyword).

The error message means what it says: that particular `SET` statement has to be in its own batch (so not mixed with any other statements).

So:

```
Use Warehouse;
GO -- this ends the batch

SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON;
GO -- this ends the batch

...
```